# How can I use a text file from the internet in my C program?

Tags: c

I'm working on a project, and I made a C program that reads the date, time, and wave height from a .txt file stored on my computer, converts the date and time to GPS time for use at a scientific research institution, and outputs GPS time and wave height to the screen.  However, the text file that I am working with is actually stored at http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/SPLL1.txt .  Is there any way that I could have my C program open the text file from the web address rather than from my local hard drive?

FYI:  to access the file on my computer I used fopen and to interact with the data contained I used a combination of fgets and fscanf.

Answer (score 4):

It is much more involved to get a web-resource than to read a file from disk, but you can absolutely do it, for example by using a library such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/).

---

An alternative strategy is to make components and tie them together with `bash` or other scripting. Your C program could for example read from standard input, and you could make a `bash` script something like this:

```
curl http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/SPLL1.txt | ./the_program
```

This way, you could keep your core C program simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I'm really new to this whole programming thing so if you don't mind:
1.  Do I have to download it?  2.  What functions should I use?

Comment: @user2619896 1. Yes, you have to download libcurl if you want to use it. 2. I linked you to the documentation. If you decide to go for libcurl, you should read it. Please come back and ask new questions if you have trouble with this :) That being said, I recommend the alternative strategy I have given.

Comment: Like I said, I'm a beginner at this so I might seem totally clueless.  I understand if you don't want to answer my probably misguided questions, but here goes anyways:  A quick google search showed that bash scripts are primarily UNIX based;  I am trying to write this in Windows 7. Is it possible for me to do this?  In your alternative strategy, what did you mean by "components"?  And is "curl" a standard function for C programs, or would I have to download libcurl regardless?  Thanks again! -Joe.

Comment: @user2619896 I'm here to answer questions! It is more that I don't want to answer every question ever in a comment thread ;) The scripting solution I had in mind works well for UNIX derivatives, and `curl` is a relatively standard command line utility here. I think it is possible to do nearly the same thing in Windows, but scripting and command line usage tends to be worse there. I am not an expert in that, tough. By "components" I mean that you could end up using the `curl` tool for talking to the web and avoid having this complexity in your program, so you wouldn't have to download `libcurl`

Comment: okay so I think I am going to go with the first option, given that it comes with a tutorial and the other option is not preferable for Windows-based machines. What specifically should I download and where should I download it to if I want to use libcurl?  http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: From the link that I gave you, there is a link to [Rosso Salmanzadeh's Using libcurl in Visual Studio guide](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf) (pdf). It seems to include instructions for what to download and how to proceed when using Visual Studio. It should answer your questions for now :)

Comment: oh ok... I am using MinGW but I think I found what I am looking for on the site you gave me.  http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-02/0076.html